# How to repeat this structure in PHP array variable

Tags: php

I have edited this question to address the answer, as the problem wasn't what I thought. When I was creating the array I was doing:

```
$points[] = array("location" => array( $markers[$j]['latitude'] , $markers[$j]['longitude'] ) );
```

For some reason it wanted:

```
$points[] = array("location" => array( floatvar($markers[$j]['latitude']) , floatvar($markers[$j]['longitude']) ) );
```

I'm not quite sure why this was the case, but it seems to have done the job for me. So the end code looked like:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($markers); $j++) {
    $points[] = array("location" => array( $markers[$j]['latitude'] , $markers[$j]['longitude'] ) );
}
```

Special thanks @D.Schaller for helping me through the debugging on chat :)

Comment: You don't seem to have as much data in `$points` as `$points2` (4 entries vs 9)

Comment: @Nick that is just because the test values in `$points2` are hard coded from the original sample code - but `$points` is based on the values passed in via AJAX (just a basic loop, which I iterate through on `$_POST['markers']` and then try to add to the `$points` array :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby For what do you use the `[j+1]` in `$_POST["markers"][j+1]`? Seems like you jump over an entry on each iterartion or am I wrong? Also there might be missing the dollar-sign `[$j+1]`?

Comment: can you var_**export** your $_POST?

Comment: @D.Schaller oops yes you are correct. Not sure why I had that! I've tweaked that to `$vals = $_POST['markers'][$j];` now, but I still get the issue. Thanks

Comment: @Andreas Have done. Please see OP

Comment: @AndrewNewby You edited a bit and made `$j <= count` to `$j < count`, did that solve your problem, because I wanted to adress that, but didn't see the editing :x

Comment: @AndrewNewby Also you realise, that `$points2 = array(...)` is corrupted with strings, right? `array("location" => array(-1.1685350,44.6591050, array("foo" => "bar") )),`. Probably that's the main reason, why you can't get it right with `$points2`

Comment: @D.Schaller thanks. I did correct that $k <= count part, but it didn't fix the problem. It actually seems to be more of a problem with the original script itself in how it works out the positions - it does `round()` and that converts it to 2dp. The problem is that most of the markers are near each other - so you could have 44.0000001 and 44.0000005, with different lngs, but then it seems this code falls over as both the numbers are 44.00 when they shouldn't be :/

Comment: That's unfortunate, but I can't think of a good reason to convert positions on long/lat to 2dp... Thats kind of a really big round up/down for coordinates.

Comment: D.Schaller yeah me either. Maybe something on this page gives a reason? http://rtsoftwaregroup.io/server-side-google-map-markers-clustering/ (this is where the original script came from). Or maybe you know of a better script to convert a list of lat/lngs into clusters, ready to use on google maps? The issue we have is that some categories are 2000+ records, and its causing major performance issues on the computers. What we need to do is create the clusters on the server rather than front end, and then only show the markers when zoomed in more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181597/discussion-between-d-schaller-and-andrew-newby).

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_intersect_key which will pick items from the array that match the $match keys.

```
// Create placeholder array to match against
$match = ['longitude' => "", 'latitude' => ""];
foreach($_POST['markers'] as $sub){
    $new[] = array_intersect_key($sub, $match);
}
var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(11) "45.26429390"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(11) "-0.91037940"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(19) "44.8247082823002360"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(20) "-0.58459281921386720"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(10) "44.6015560"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(20) "-1.08606009999994060"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(10) "44.7300940"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(20) "-1.04289489999996470"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(20) "-1.17691170000000510"
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(10) "44.6437140"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(18) "45.068182578090370"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(20) "-1.14553928375244140"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(15) "-0.593261718750"
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(18) "44.331707186809210"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(18) "44.721281586556690"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(21) "-0.453948412793351960"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(18) "44.833484299999990"
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(20) "-0.56840629999999240"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["longitude"]=>
    string(20) "-0.58094501495361330"
    ["latitude"]=>
    string(18) "45.144727399384470"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/5Siqs

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've just updated the question with a bit more info. The problem with your solution, is that I do actually want the rest of the values passed in as well (not just **latitude** and **longitude**), thus my approach. When the code is fully working it will need to  return the values from that marker if its not in a cluster (so it can be shown on the map). I took that part out of the code though as its not relevant for this part of the question :)